# Given Assembly, translate to C

Tags: c, assembly, att, x86

I am originally given the function prototype:

```
void decode1(int *xp, int *yp, int *zp)
```

now i am told to convert the following assembly into C code:

```
movl 8(%ebp), %edi //line 1 ;; gets xp
movl 12(%ebp), %edx //line 2 ;; gets yp
movl 16(%ebp),%ecx //line 3 ;; gets zp
movl (%edx), %ebx //line 4 ;; gets y
movl (%ecx), %esi //line 5 ;; gets z
movl (%edi), %eax //line 6 ;; gets x
movl %eax, (%edx) //line 7 ;; stores x into yp
movl %ebx, (%ecx) //line 8 ;; stores y into zp
movl %esi, (%edi) //line 9 ;; stores z into xp
```

These comments were not given to me in the problem this is what I believe they are doing but am not 100% sure.

My question is, for lines 4-6, am I able to assume that the command

```
movl (%edx), %ebx 
movl (%ecx), %esi
movl (%edi), %eax
```

just creates a local variables to y,z,x?

also, do the registers that each variable get stored in i.e (edi,edx,ecx) matter or can I use any register in any order to take the pointers off of the stack?

C code:

```
int tx = *xp;
int ty = *yp;
int tz = *zp;
*yp = tx;
*zp = ty;
*xp = tz;
```

If I wasn't given the function prototype how would I tell what type of return type is used?

Comment: You need to familiarize yourself with the concept of _function calling conventions_, the steps followed by compiled code to call other compiled code. [For x86, you can read about them here.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_calling_conventions). There are no true local variables in assembler; There are only reads from memory into registers, operations in registers, and writes from registers to memory. The code can, however reserve space on the stack by modifying `%esp`, and use this space as it so pleases (including the storing of so-called local variables).

Comment: okay I will look into that, its just difficult to manage what I am supposed to learn for school and what is actually practical in the real world lol @IwillnotexistIdonotexist

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's focus on a simpler set of instructions.

First:

```
movl 8(%ebp), %edi
```

will load into the EDI register the content of the 4 bytes that are situated on memory at 8 eight bytes beyond the address set in the EBP register. This special EBP usage is a convention followed by the compiler code generator, that per each function, saves the stack pointer ESP into the EBP registers, and then creates a stack frame for the function local variables.

Now, in the EDI register, we have the first parameter passed to the function, that is a pointer to an integer, so EDI contains now the address of that integer, but not the integer itself.

```
movl (%edi), %eax
```

will get the 4 bytes pointed by the EDI register and load them into the EAX register.

Now in EAX we have the value of the integer pointed by the `xp` in the first parameter.

And then:

```
movl %eax, (%edx)
```

will save this integer value into the memory pointed by the content of the EDX register which was in turn loaded from EBP+12 which is the second parameter passed to the function.

So, your first question, is this assembly code equivalent to this?

```
int tx = *xp;
int ty = *yp;
int tz = *zp;
*yp = tx;
*zp = ty;
*xp = tz;
```

is, **yes**, but note that there are no `tx,ty,tz` local variables created, but just processor registers.

And your second question, is **no**, you can't tell the type of return, it is, again, a convention on the register usage that you can't infer just by looking at the generated assembly code.

Comment: so since there are no local variables created I am still able to create them in C and name them anything as long as they are the right type correct? like me naming it tx or naming it x wouldn't change anything ? @PA.

Comment: @bkennedy: right, local variables are just placeholders.  They can exist only in registers.  And their names make no difference.  If you look at compiler output with no optimizations, gcc would typically emit code that stores `tx` on the stack, then loads it again before storing the value into `*yp`.  But `-Og` will make sane code that never spills it from the register.

Comment: it is so, but in some old c compilers, you could hint the compilers to help them optimizing the local variables, by specifying the `register` reserved keyword. It's somewhat deprecated because in general modern compilers are better than human programmers to figure out such optimizations.

Answer (score 4):

Congratulations, you got everything right :)

You can use any register but some need to be preserved, that is they should be saved before use and restored afterwards. In typical calling conventions you can use `eax`, `ecx` and `edx`, the rest need to be preserved. The assembly you showed doesn't include code to do this, but presumably it is there.

As for the return type, that's hard to deduce. Simple types are returned in the `eax` register, and something is always in there. We can't tell if that's intended as a return value, or just remains of a local variable. That is, if your function had `return tx;` it could be the same assembly code. Also, we don't know the type for `eax` either, it could be anything that fits in there and is expected to be returned there according to the calling convention.